# Can't put text into commit message - it all comes out garbled

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am getting the following when I try to commit using TortoiseSVN. I am using the latest 64bit version of TortoiseSVN: 1.9.2. Does anyone know why this happens or how to correct this?

[image]

Comment: is the  tsvn:projectlanguage property set with the wrong value?

Comment: @Stefan: where would that be set? This is happening for all the projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings dialog, Advanced: set the ScintillaDirect2D to 'false'.
If that helps, then the problem is your graphic card/driver.